# Compute the eigenvectors in lapack using predetermined eigenvalues?

Tags: c, performance, math, lapack, intel-mkl

I have a rather unusual challenge for lapack, and I have spent hours searching for a solution to it.

I have a generalized eigenvalue problem of the traditional form (A - x B = 0). Normally I would use for instance ?hegvx or ?hegvd to calculate the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors.

However the challenge I am facing now, is now that I already know the eigenvalues from the construction of the problem, and therefore I need an **efficient** lapack routine for calculating the eigenvectors only?

Anyone got a hack for this?

Comment: You'd want to compute the null space (aka. kernel) of the matrix A-xE, but I don't know the LAPACK (or BLAS?) routine for that either.

Answer (score 3):

Given the generalised eigenvalue problem

(A - y B) x = 0

And an eigenvalue yn:

(A - y<sub>n</sub> B) x<sub>n</sub> = 0

We know A, B and yn, so we can form a new matrix Cn

C<sub>n</sub> = A - y<sub>n</sub> B

C<sub>n</sub> x<sub>n</sub> = 0

You can solve this with any linear algebra solver individually for each eigenvalue. According to the [LAPACK docs on linear equations](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node38.html), for a general matrix, double precision, you might use DGETRS

Edit for degenerate eigenvalues:

The null space of the matrix Cn is what we are solving for here (as MvG commented). If

C<sub>n</sub> j = 0 and 
  C<sub>n</sub> k = 0

(i.e. degenerate e-vals) then given j<sup>T</sup>k = 0 (both are still eigenvectors of the AB system) we can say

Call a row of C<sub>n</sub> r:

r.k = r.k - j<sup>T</sup>.k = (r-j<sup>T</sup>).k

Thus forming a matrix J whose rows are each j<sup>T</sup> (there must be a name for this, but I don't know it):

(C<sub>n</sub> - J) k = 0

Define

D<sub>nj</sub> = C<sub>n</sub> - J

And now solve for the new matrix D<sub>nj</sub>. By construction this will be a new, orthogonal eigenvector of the original matrix with the same degenerate eigenvalue.

Comment: I will try this, however if it is efficient, time will show. At the top of my head the big challenge with your suggested approach, would be for degenerated eigenvalues.

Comment: I'll reply in the post for clarity and notation.